# Secure some keys in application.properties - spring boot application

Tags: spring, git, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where I am using some aws services.
The code in openly available in Git. 
I don't want to commit AWS secret and access keys which are part of application.properties. I can't add to .gitignore as I want to commit other values of application.properties.

Many are committing to this repo. We are adding these aws keys in local and making sure its not added as part of any commit.

I want to make sure the aws keys in application.properties should not come to git at any cost. Which is the best way to manage these secret keys.?

Comment: you should use credentials file for aws authentication!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Mark B. I would prefer using Java system properties as we can maintain them at application level. Env variables will be at system level which is not really needed and it may lead to conflicts.

while running an spring-boot jar with mvn, it can be done as below

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Daws.accessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXX -Daws.secretKey=XXXXXXXXXXX"`

if running for IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, it should be added as VM Options.

`-Daws.accessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXX -Daws.secretKey=XXXXXXXXXXXX`

After this AWS client object can be built as usual. 
As an example,

1. SNS client can be build by

`AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClient.builder().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();`

2. SES client can be built by

`AmazonSimpleEmailService emailClient = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();`

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be placing AWS API keys in application.properties at all. If the application is running on AWS it should be using the IAM role of the server it is running on. If it is not running on AWS it should probably be using environment variables.

Please review the documentation on this subject [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html).